# Laravel Custom validation rule with parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-validation

I have write this function rule in `CustomRequest` to check checkHackInputUser rule that define in provider:

> Actually i want to check the value that pass in route

for example :

```
 http://www.somedomain.com/user/{id}
```

> I what do some operation on this $id variable
>   with my checkHackInputUser rule

Here is CustomRequest:

```
public function rules()
{

$request_id = $this->route('user');
$rules = [];

if($this->method() == "DELETE" || $this->method() == "GET" )
    $rules = [
        'role_list'             => 'required|checkHackInputUser:'.$request_id,
    ];

return $rules;
}
```

The problem is,this `rule(checkHackInputUser)` doesn't work if i remove `required` role.

Here is the checkHackInputUser validation function in provider:

```
public function boot()
{

    $this->app['validator']->extend('checkHackInputUser',function($attr,$value,$params){

            //Some validation

            return false or true;

});

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can [conditionally validate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) input when present using `sometimes`.

> In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to your rule list:
>
> $v = Validator::make($data, [
>       'email' => 'sometimes|required|email',
>   ]);

Comment: my problem is my variable is not persent on input array

Comment: its route url variable